# PHP For Loop strange issue

Tags: php, string, loops, random, for-loop

Any reason why this code sometimes only generates 4 character strings?

```
function genID()
{
    $id     = '';
    $values = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) :
        $str = substr($values, rand(0, strlen($values)), 1);
        if(!is_nan(acos($str)))
            (mt_rand(0, 1)) ? $str = strtoupper($str) : '';
        $id .= $str;
    endfor;

    return $id; // e.g: ifR8j
}
```

Comment: What on earth is         if(!is_nan(acos($str))) 
            (mt_rand(0, 1)) ? $str = strtoupper($str) : ''; 
supposed to be doing? Why are you trying to apply trigonometric functions to characters?

Comment: from manual of [`acos`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.acos.php) `float acos ( float $arg )`$arg is 'The arc cosine of arg in radians.'

Comment: I did it for pure lazyness, I could take it out and just manually enter the A-Z but that still doesn't answer why it sometimes returns 4?

Comment: much easier functions for random 4 digit id generation

Comment: I'd say that sometimes, acos($str) (arccos of a character?!? Wait, what?) is not a number *and* mt_rand returns a `0`. Therefore, you get to the `''` part of your condition at line 9. Does exactly what you are asking it to do ;) the question is, what are you *trying* to do with that condition on lines 8-9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, something simple:

```
function genID() {
    $id = '';
    $i = $length = 4;
    $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz";
    $possibleChar = strlen($possible) - 1;
    while ($i) {
        $char = $possible[mt_rand(0, $possibleChar)];
        while (!strstr($id, $char)) {
            $id .= $char;
            $i--;
        }
    }

    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

acos($str) accepts numbers not string.... if u remove the aphabets from the string

ie.

`$values = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`

to

```
$values = '0123456789';
```

you will get the length as 5... Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
 (mt_rand(0, 1)) ? $str = strtoupper($str) : '';
```

This condition is met so sometimes you get an empty char.

Fix the condition or do the loop in some other manner. 
For example

```
while(strlen($id)<5) {
   //do the loop
}
```

Comment: btw. you are complicating way to much with mt_rabdm acos etc

Comment: ah, good, the solution too. `rand(0, strlen - 1)` would do too.

Answer (score 0):

The loop iterates 5 times.

`rand` will also return `strlen`, so `$str` will sometimes be `""`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = substr($values, rand(0, strlen($values))-1, 1);
```

This will generate 5 characters always.